# How to access a deleted recurring appointment occurrence via Outlook interop

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin

Hi I have a piece of C# code that access exception appointments in an Outlook appointment recurrence pattern. I realised that when ever the code try to access the `AppointmentItem` property of the `Exception` object, if the `Exception.Deleted` is `true`, there will be a COM exception saying "**You changed one of the recurrences of this item, and this instance no longer exists. Close any open items and try again.**"

The master `AppointmentItem` object I obtain in my code is straight from the `Folder.Items.ItemChange` event and this is an extract of the code:

```
private static void OnAppointmentChanged(AppointmentItem appointment)
{
    if(appointment.IsRecurring)
    {
        var pattern = outlookAppointment.GetRecurrencePattern();
        foreach (Exception e in pattern.Exceptions)
        {
            // This will throw the exception if e.Deleted == true.
            var occurence = e.AppointmentItem;
        }
    }
}
```

Although this question has been [discussed here in the Visual Studio forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/25da44e3-3626-42ab-abe5-e3f18d7d118d), but the marked solution is not really a solution because my Outlook 2013 is a higher version (15.0.4693.1001 32-bit) than the one mentioned in the solution.

Does anyone have any idea why this is so?

Answer (score 1):

The [Deleted](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866718(v=office.15).aspx) property of the Exception class returns a boolean value that indicates whether the AppointmentItem was deleted from the recurring pattern. It may not exist on the calendar anymore.

You can handle the [BeforeDelete](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869458(v=office.15).aspx) event of the AppointnentItem class which is fired before an item (which is an instance of the parent object) is deleted. An instance of the Appointment item is passed as a parameter. You may also cancel the action setting the Cancel parameter to true.

Most probably there is a better solution which may suits your needs. Why do you need to access non-existing items?

Comment: Thanks for the answer Eugene. I need to access the deleted item because I am working on an app that syncs the Outlook appointments to it's own calendar (which is using a DevExpress scheduler control).

Handling the BeforeDelete event might work but that also means that I have to hook up event handler to every appointment item in all calendar folders that I need to sync. Sounds a bit over kill though.

Comment: There is no other way to get the information about deleted appointments.

Comment: The exception is just, that the master item does not occur on exception.OriginalDate.